# How to create a vector drawable with inner path transparent?

Tags: android, shapes, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to create a favourite icon something like the following icon.

[image]

While creating it i need the inner path (the area in blue color)to be transparent in the result.But while giving the transparent color it is showing the color that is filled in the  outer path.i.e complete shape in orange color. How i can i make a vector drawable with transparent inner path

My vector drawable is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="72dp"
        android:height="66dp"
        android:viewportHeight="66"
        android:viewportWidth="72">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:pathData="M 0.00 0.00 L 72.00 0.00 L 72.00 66.00 L 0.00 66.00 L 0.00 0.00 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#F7592B"
        android:pathData="M 20.99 1.04 C 26.30 1.45 30.97 4.88 36.04 5.70 C 40.02 5.23 43.79 2.79 47.70
        1.80 C 56.08 -0.90 65.46 4.21 69.03 11.97 C 71.67 17.65 71.59 24.74 70.62 30.81
        C 68.57 41.48 60.32 50.55 51.81 56.81 C 47.69 59.73 43.11 62.72 38.21 64.12 C
        34.80 65.13 31.23 63.34 28.24 61.86 C 19.69 57.27 11.77 50.76 6.25 42.72 C 0.82
        34.78 -0.33 24.87 1.66 15.60 C 3.69 7.15 12.14 0.18 20.99 1.04 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#1721dc"
        android:pathData="M 19.98 7.14 C 25.68 7.39 30.87 12.07 36.10 12.99 C 41.30 12.15 46.97 7.14 52.84
        7.35 C 58.72 7.85 63.41 12.52 64.67 18.17 C 65.71 23.40 65.21 29.32 63.25 34.30
        C 59.83 42.88 52.20 49.81 44.38 54.43 C 40.52 56.53 36.81 58.58 32.37 56.70 C
        24.56 53.51 17.02 47.75 12.20 40.77 C 7.31 33.87 5.58 24.79 7.64 16.59 C 9.15
        11.09 14.21 6.98 19.98 7.14 Z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: no you can't.. you should use illustrator to make svg like that and convert to vector drawable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to go:
1) create another vector drawable, which will draw only the outer line, instead of overlapping two hearts
or
2) remove the orange heart and add an orange stroke to the blue heart. Just copy the code below and try it. Be aware: half of the stroke width will go inside the image and half will go outside, so your image will differ a bit (stoke will be closer to the center of the image)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="72dp"
    android:height="66dp"
    android:viewportHeight="66"
    android:viewportWidth="72">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeColor="#F7592B"
        android:strokeWidth="6"
        android:pathData="M 19.98 7.14 C 25.68 7.39 30.87 12.07 36.10 12.99 C 41.30 12.15 46.97 7.14 52.84
        7.35 C 58.72 7.85 63.41 12.52 64.67 18.17 C 65.71 23.40 65.21 29.32 63.25 34.30
        C 59.83 42.88 52.20 49.81 44.38 54.43 C 40.52 56.53 36.81 58.58 32.37 56.70 C
        24.56 53.51 17.02 47.75 12.20 40.77 C 7.31 33.87 5.58 24.79 7.64 16.59 C 9.15
        11.09 14.21 6.98 19.98 7.14 Z" />
</vector>
```

Result:[click to see the resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZgPK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please use StrokeColor and strokeWidth like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="72dp"
android:height="66dp"
android:viewportHeight="66"
android:viewportWidth="72">

<path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:pathData="M 0.00 0.00 L 72.00 0.00 L 72.00 66.00 L 0.00 66.00 L 0.00 0.00 Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000000"
    android:pathData="M 19.98 7.14 C 25.68 7.39 30.87 12.07 36.10 12.99 C 41.30 12.15 46.97 7.14 52.84
    7.35 C 58.72 7.85 63.41 12.52 64.67 18.17 C 65.71 23.40 65.21 29.32 63.25 34.30
    C 59.83 42.88 52.20 49.81 44.38 54.43 C 40.52 56.53 36.81 58.58 32.37 56.70 C
    24.56 53.51 17.02 47.75 12.20 40.77 C 7.31 33.87 5.58 24.79 7.64 16.59 C 9.15
    11.09 14.21 6.98 19.98 7.14 Z"
    android:strokeColor="#F7592B"
    android:strokeWidth="5"/>
```

Comment: Followed your suggestion and created my vector image with strokes :)